# MIPS - Load Word behavior

Tags: mips, spim

Fellow SO users

I'm hoping someone could explain the behavior that I am experiencing whilst using SPIM to run my MIPS code. I'm implementing an encryption algorithm and one of the steps is loading the encryption key which is 64 bits wide. For example, if the encryption key is `0x123456789ABCDEF0`, I'm declaring it in the following way;

```
.data
    enc_key_lo: 0x78563412
    enc_key_hi: 0xF0DEBC9A
```

Now, whenever I load `enc_key_lo` first, I check to see whether I encounter a `0` so that I can load `enc_key_hi`. The following is my code;

```
.text
la $a1, enc_key_lo
la $a2, enc_key_hi

load_lo:
    lbu $s0, 0($a1) 
    addi $a1, $a1, 1      
    beq $s0, $zero, load_hi  #If 0, then we need to load enc_key_hi
    j load_lo

load_hi:
    lbu $s1, 0($a2)
    addi $s2, $s2, 1
    /* DO SOME OPERATIONS ETC ETC */
```

When I run the code, I observe the register `$s0` loads with the following on successive iterations of the `load_lo` loop;

```
12, 34, 56, 78, 9A, BC, DE, F0
```

I was expecting register `$s0` to load with 0 after loading `78` but it keeps loading all the way till `F0`. Hence, this defeats the purpose of having the `load_hi` segment in the code. I noticed that if I commented out the declaration `enc_key_hi`, then `$s0` is loaded with `0` after loading with `78`.

Could someone please explain this behavior?
Kind regards.

Comment: Why do you expect `$s0` to see zero after 0x78? The data sits in memory exactly as you typed it in the data segment (without zeros).

Comment: Hi Omri, so how is the end of the string represented in memory for MIPS? There is no NULL character to compare with is there?

Comment: A value is just taken as a word - not as a string. If you want to store a string you need to tell the assembler the type of the data. For example: `enc_key_lo: .asciiz "hello"` which will put the characters `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, `'\0'` in the data segment. But why would you want to store encryption keys as null-terminated strings?